# Convert JSON Sub Class to DataTable (C#)

Tags: c#, json, class, datatable

I imported some JSON contents and created a class to deserialize them.

```
public class CONTENTSFROMSERVER
{
    public List<DATA> data { get; set; }
    public META meta { get; set; }
    public LINKS links { get; set; }
}
public class DATA
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public ATTRIBUTES attributes { get; set; }
}
public class ATTRIBUTES
{
    public string field_01 { get; set; }
    public string field_02 { get; set; }
    public string field_03 { get; set; }
}
...
```

So far so good (the class is not complete in this post because the missing part is not important for the question).

Then I get the content response from the request:

```
String contents = Resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

And finally I deserialize that content into the `CONTENTSFROMSERVER` class:

```
var Values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CONTENTSFROMSERVER>(contents);
```

Everything is working fine and I have no trouble on the last part.

What I want, if anyone knows how to do it, is to fill a `DataTable` with the data from the `ATTRIBUTES` class.

Something like:

```
DataTable datatable = Values.data.attributes;
```

Is there a simple way to do it? Or do I have to construct the datatable, retrieve the values from the class and fill the datatable later? And, if so, how may I do it?

I know there are a lot of posts about this matter on the web and even on this site, but I can't find an answer to my specific question.

**APPEND:** How is my question a duplicate of the suggested linked questions??? I really though I was been explicit.

Comment: What's the specific question though? Why do you want a DataTable and what do you expect it to contain? All UI elements (web or desktop) can bind to lists of objects. There are LINQ extensions that convert objects to a DataTable BUT if you want to insert the data into a database it's better to create a DbDataReader instead. FastMember's [ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#ever-needed-an-idatareader) can create an IDataReader from any `IEnumerable<T>`  that can be used with SqlBulkCopy or `DataTable.Load`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I want a `datatable` because it's better for the next part of the program that I'm writing and I think I was pretty explicit on my demand: fill the datatable with the values from the `ATTRIBUTES` class (`field_01`, `field_02` and `field_03`). I'm sorry for the eventual lack of details on my speech.

Comment: Why is it better? What does the next part of the program do? It *does* matter - a DataTable is a copy of the original data, so it's better to use an IDataReader if possible. In any case, I posted duplicates that show both options. If they don't work, you'll have to explain the actual problem

Comment: I'm sorry. What happened to `SO`? Really?! I think I don't have to expose WHY I want to work with a datatable. I simply asked how is it done. You may suggest an alternative but in No way is this question a duplicate of that.

Comment: Why not? What *is* the question? You never explained that. If you only want to convert a *single* object to a table with a single row, just put that object into an array and use *any* of the duplicates. `var table =new[] {attributes}.ToDataTable();`.